# Can we call a function inside a cmake generator expression?

Tags: cmake

Variables like `$<TARGET_OBJECTS:myTarget>` can contain a list. To pretty-print it I would like to transform like put a dash, or whatever. So the question is simple : can we call a function from a generator expression ?

I know generator expressions are evaluated at the end of the process, but for me it doesn't implies it can't call a function. However, it's not possible to return a value. If this is possible, is there a way to use it inside generator expressions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call a function for the result of a generator expression, because generator expressions are evaluated **after** the *configuration* stage, when all CMake functions are executed.

For pretty-printing a list you could use `$<JOIN>` expression.
For example,

```
$<JOIN $<TARGET_OBJECTS:myTarget>,$<COMMA> >
```

will concatenate all objects and paste `,`  between them.

Comment: What is the purpose of the double quote (`"`) in your generator expression?

Comment: @AlexReinking: Sorry, it was a typo. Fixed now.

Comment: But even if generator expressions are evaluated at the end of the configuration process, it doesn't implies that it can't call some code inside a function. Is it just a limitation of CMake or there is some reasoning ?

Comment: @rafoo: Well, it is more correct to say that generator expressions are evaluated **after** the configuration process. At the time of evaluation no CMake code is executed. I have fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I know generator expressions are evaluated at runtime, so the function should also be [evaluated] at runtime.

What do you mean by "runtime"? That's not a thing in CMake. There's *configuration* time and *generation* time, which are different. Functions run during configuration and generator expressions are expanded during generation, so you cannot call a CMake function from a generator expression.

> Plus, it's not possible to return a value. If this is possible, is there a way to use it inside generator expressions?

Indeed, functions in CMake do not have return values.

Comment: Yeah I meant generation time, confused by runtime/compilation time concepts in C++. I edited the question.